# Unable to find image 'de:latest' locally - Docker

Tags: image, docker

Good night, I'm having problems that I can't find a solution on the internet, I'm trying to map directories to the container, the terminal complains about an error saying that the image "de" could not be found, and I specified that the image is "nginx" . I've searched the internet and was unable to find a solution, who can help me thank you in advance.

```
$ sudo docker container run -p 8080:80 -v S(pwd)/html:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx 
Unable to find image 'de:tatest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for de, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of text. Just include the text itself in your question, properly formatted. This will make it more likely that people will take the time to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this is not taking nginx as an image argument, your `$(pwd)` as per the image attached contains `Area de .....` hence the argument with a space after `Area` is improperly parsed as image argument. Consider using `quotes` to wrap your `$(pwd)` as Step 1. If it doesnt work use below script to escape sequence all spaces in your `pwd` 
 `pwd | sed 's/ /\\ /g'` 
 Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was fact, my desktop had several spaces between "Área de Trabalho" so that made the code understand that that space would be the argument of the Docker image. But now it's all right and working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using put quotes around **PWD**.

And my command is:

```
sudo docker container run -p 8080:80 -v "$PWD":/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```